# Querying Firebase Data by Child

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am now long working with swift and Firebase but face the issue that one of my queries doesn't work properly.

Each of my messages has a creation Date assigned and I can call it from the data when I load the messages but I am not able to load it by the child "creationDate" which is my node for the timestamp.

My message is sent like in a chat app and there is no issue, following is my code for querying the data.
As I mentioned the path is correct and the code is just for testing purposes

**Note** : this is just a code snippet in order to test if the path is correct

```
    func checkMessages() {
    guard let currentUser = API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else {return}
    API.Message.REF_MESSAGES_CHAT.child(currentUser).queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            for key in dict.keys {

                if let value = dict[key] as? [String:Any] {
                    let creationDate = value["creationDate"] as! Double
                    let text = value["text"] as! String

                    print("creation:" , creationDate)
                    print("text:", text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the print out would be

```
creation: 1514041174.13297
text: 8
creation: 1514041177.54951
text: 10
creation: 1514041171.24212
text: 6
creation: 1514041172.35241
text: 7
creation: 1514041168.06832
text: 3
creation: 1514041166.98511
text: 2
creation: 1514041170.10783
text: 5
creation: 1514041165.88657
text: 1
creation: 1514041169.09632
text: 4
creation: 1514041175.60879
text: 9
```

I sent them ordered properly ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).
Any idea?
I am really struggling at this point because I have this feature implemented over 30 times in my app and nowhere else its an issue just in querying this.

Edit: upload of a message

```
        let creationDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let timestamp = ["creationDate": creationDate, "text": text] as [String : Any]
    API.Message.REF_MESSAGES_CHAT.child(currentUser).child(newMessageID).setValue(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
API.Message.REF_MESSAGES_CHAT.child(currentUser).queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in ... }
```

Comment: ups I cut the piece before I asked to test if the query will be different, I obviously have it in my code :D it doesn't work

Comment: Try to use let creationDate = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

Comment: What would that change? Because I have it all around my app exactly the same way and it works fine despite here, but I will try it though

Comment: I just use it in my firebase app and everything work fine, so i don't know, may be this will help

Comment: How do you generate a newMessageID ?

Comment: let newMessageID = API.Message.REF_MESSAGE.child(currentUser).child(self.userId).childByAutoId().key. The userID is my chat partner to save all messages generally

Comment: Documentation says that if you use childByAutoId(), nodes are ordered automatically even without queryOrdered, so it is really strange that you have such result.

Comment: One mire thing: if I just load it from firebase its shown correctly ordered, but I implemented a pagination so that the app doesn't crash if there are too many messages. when I load more messages they are loaded in exactly the opposite way they should be (starting 10,9,8,7 and if I load 3 more its 4,5,6 instead of 6,5,4) so its ordered but incorrectly